# Sleeping in onTouchEvent blocks onSensorChanged

Tags: android, multithreading, listener, accelerometer, sensors

I'm making an application which will utilize both touchevents and sensorevents. The problem with touchevents is that they fire off very often, and thereby consumes massive amounts of CPU time. The common solution is to do a Thread.sleep to make it cool down.

However, if one wants to use both the onTouchEvent and onSensorChanged in the same activity, applying the Thread.sleep hack will also slow down onSensorChanged. This is obviously caused by the two methods being called from the same (ui) thread.

Is there some way to call onTouchEvent from a different thread than the ui, so one could do the Thread.sleep trick without slowing down onSensorChanged as well?

Answer (score 0):

"The common solution is to do a Thread.sleep to make it cool down."

Where did you hear that? Sleeping on the main thread (also called EDT - event dispatching thread) is not acceptable. Android is redrawing the screen and doing all kinds of tasks on this thread. Sleeping it can make it unresponsive and is IMHO a bad practice.

If onTouchEvent() are firing too often then just filter them in your code = do nothing if at least X amount of time has not passed since last event.

```
long lastTime = 0; // field in you class holding event handler

// inside your onTouchEvent handler
if(System.getCurrentTimeMillis() - lastTime < XXX)
    return;
 lastTime = System.getCurrentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that it is not what happens inside onTouchEvent which slows it down, but rather that it is being called at all. Even with an empty onTouchEvent there are noticeable lags to onSensorChanged.

Comment: Unfortunately one can not control how many events Android fires.